# Why does the html not consistently right-align and style the figures in the cells

Tags: html, sql-server, html-rendering, sp-send-dbmail

[image]

```html
<html>
<head>
<style> .inkclass {text-align: right;} </style>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Company Name</h3>
<table border = "1">
<tr>
<th>Group</th>
<th>Units</th>
<th>Selling Excl.</th>
<th>Cost Value</th>
<th>GP Value</th>
<th>GP %</th>
<th>Selling Incl.</th>
<th>Budget Value</th>
<th>Budget %</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Group</td>
<td class="inkclass">10</td>
<td class="inkclass">2,892.00</td>
<td class="inkclass">1,055.56</td>
<td class="inkclass">1,836.44</td>
<td class="inkclass">63.50</td>
<td class="inkclass">3,325.80</td>
<td class="inkclass">180,000.00</td>
<td class="inkclass">1.61</td>
</tr>
```

In the following html code that is being generated by a ms-sql query, the output is consistent. However, when that output is sent via sql db mail with body_format='html', the alignment and style of the figures in the cells is not rendered consistently (viewed in gmail), even though every "td" has the same class.

```html
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'such-and-such',
@recipients = 'xyz@gmail.com;',
@subject = 'whatever',
@body = '',
@body_format = 'html',
@query = 'the-query-name-is-here',
@execute_query_database = 'the-db',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 0
```

Comment: The `@body_format` is for when using the `@body` parameter. The resulting dataset from `@query` will always be textual data (it won't contain any formatting for HTML display). The documentation covers how to send an HTML dataset: [Sending an HTML e-mail message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#c-sending-an-html-e-mail-message)

Comment: thank you, working, just needed to add the 'text-align:right' as 'td/@style', before each td=column